# MySQL java communication

Tags: java, mysql, percona

I wonder if there is a way to connect mysql with java client, what i mean is:

if user updated record from machien2 then mysql will send signal to other users on the network, that tell the users (there is a new record added or updated).

so, is this possible? or i need to make an auto refresh method on my java application so the data can be updated each 5 seconds for example, but the problem is this method will cost me a bandwidth, so if i can refresh only when data added or updated then that will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think thats not possible with any DBMS, for such appications you can use JMS (Java Messageing Service). My preferred imlementation is [HornetQ](https://www.jboss.org/hornetq/) from JBoss. You find other implementations at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service

With there you should use the Publish/Subscribe Pattern to send and recive events.

Comment: i'm developing a desktop application, Java client with Percona(MySQL) database server.

Comment: also desktop applications can subscripe to an JMS Topic/Queue

Comment: Cool, so could you please just tell the idea with an example, how to work with JMS + MySQL + Java.

Comment: you start with an JMS Server, there you configure a Topic, the Clients are connecting to that topic. When now a client writes something to the DB, he has to notifiy the others via the topic (publish a message). The other clients recives the message from the JMS server and can lookup the DB for changes. EDIT: or you send the data directly through JMS (I don't know what kind of application you are developing)

Comment: its a hospital management system, patient record & financial record could be added or updated at any time, so i need to make client have the latest information's directly.

Comment: why are the clients are directly connected to the database - i think this is a great securtiy and performance issue! Consider to use technologies like EJB and JPA